# Primefaces checkboxes inside p:dataTable mixed on row deleted

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

Spring Webflow 2.4.1, Spring 1.1, JSF 2.2.3 and Primefaces 5.1

I have a dataTable for which, in every row, are present 2 boolean checkboxes to modify a field. The user can modify the entries or remove a whole row.

```
<h:form id="editForm">
<p:dataTable id="permissionTable" var="sdp" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" value="${serverDirectoryPermissions}">                  
<p:column>
   <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="name" />
   </f:facet>
   <div>
      <h:outputText value="${sdp.name}"/>
   </div>
</p:column>
<p:column>
   <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="upload permission" />
   </f:facet>
   <div>
      <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="canUploadCheck" value="${sdp.hasUploadPermission}" />
   </div>
</p:column>
<p:column>
   <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="delete permission" />
   </f:facet>
   <div>
      <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="canDeleteCheck" value="${sdp.hasDeletePermission}" />
   </div>
</p:column>
<p:column>
   <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="&nbsp;&nbsp;" />
   </f:facet>
   <div>
      <p:commandButton id="removePermission" value="${tmsg.messages.sys_button_remove}" action="${documentManager.removeServerDirectoryPermission(serverDirectoryPermissions,sdp)}" ajax="true" process=":editForm" update=":editForm" immediate="true"/>
   </div>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

When clicked the remove button fires an action that removes the selected entry from the original list, and then the ajax call refreshes the form (and so the table)

```
public void removeServerDirectoryPermission(List<ServerDirectoryPermission> sdps, ServerDirectoryPermission sdpToRemove) {
   sdps.remove(sdpToRemove);

}
```

When the table refreshes, the correct row is removed. The problem is that all the checkboxes below the deleted row take the value of the row that was directly above them.

e.g.

row1 true false
row2 false true
row3 true true
row4 false false

after I delete row2:

row1 true false
row3 false true
row4 true true

I debugged the back end and the values in the beans for row3 and row4 are not being updated yet, so it's only the GUI that displays the wrong values. Offc ourse if I save the new values are saved.

Am I doing something wrong in the way I delete entries and update the datatable?

For completenes the serverDirectoryPermissions is a list in a flowScope variable and it get persisted in the database when a save button is pressed. The save process works correctly so I omitted the code.

Thanks a lot

**>>> EDIT <<<**

I added some ids to the Primefaces components and I noticed that when JSF rebuild the table after the Ajax update, all the ids are shifted. So, in the example above:

row1 checkbox_id0
row2 checkbox_id1
row3 checkbox_id2
row4 checkbox_id3

after delete:

row1 checkbox_id0
row3 checkbox_id1
row4 checkbox_id2

As I can verify that the correct row has been deleted from the list, I suspect that JSF is storing the input values by ids. After the row is removed the ids are shift, but JSF ignores this and keeps a map of values based on the original ids. In fact if after this I add a new row, this one is automatically populated with the values of checkbox_id3.

How could I tell JSF that a row has been removed? should I try to manipulate directly the dataTable from the backend?

Comment: Why are you dependent upon the row index to delete a row? Choose another way to delete an entry. Use `#` in Facelets (not `$`). This conditional check,  `if (sdp.getId() == sdpToRemove.getId()) {...}` will require comparing objects using `equals()` unless either both or one of them holds a primitive type.

Comment: Hi, I'm not using the row index. I use an iterator to cycle the list and find the index of the element I want to remove from the list. The method removes the right element and the table reflect this. It's only the checkbox inputs that keep hold of a wrong value. 
I replaced the check with equals() and replaced the $ with #, but no luck. Thanks anyway

Comment: @malavock Have u overridden equals and hashCode for ServerDirectoryPermission.java. If yes then change your #{documentManager.removeServerDirectoryPermission(serverDirectoryPermissions,sdp)} to #${documentManager.removeServerDirectoryPermission(sdp)}       In the removeServerDirectoryPermission method call  serverDirectoryPermissions.remove(sdp). Am i right in assuming serverDirectoryPermissions is Named and u have Inject it in DocumentManager.java?

Comment: I didn't override the equals before, I did it now and updated the code but no luck. I know the right entry in the list is deleted, because the "name" shown in every row is the correct one.
I notice now the specification part has been cut off. I'm using Spring WebFlow so serverDirectoryPermissions is a flowScope variable and it's not directly injected in the Document Manager. I have some updates I'm gonna edit the post.